# Game Center multiplayer, very long connection timeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timeout, gamekit, game-center

I've implemented a 2-player turnbased game using Game Center matchmaking/multiplayer, in other words using `GKMatch`. It works well. There is just one issue: when one player disconnects (ie. quits the app), it takes a while before the other players gets notified of this (with `match:player:didChangeState:`). Sometimes even 30 seconds.

That is not a good UX. I don't want a player to wait for nothing if the other player already disconnected 30 seconds ago.

2 questions:

- **Is this an issue with the sandbox server only?**
- **If not, what can I do to shorten/eliminate this waiting period?**

Comment: Maybe it's just caused by a network issue. Have you tried with another network?

Comment: Hello,I am having similar type of issue.I have implemented multiple player game with 4player.Now when 1 player get disconnected rest all 3 player get disconnected.What i want is if 1player will get disconnect then rest 3 should continue to play. Is it possible.And

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not rely on GC's notifyPlayer.. Everything from DC to quit game to receive calls i handle by my own codes..

for my code, when player A presses home button, means in app delegate's applicationDidEnterBackground, a data is sent to the player B to inform that player A has quit the game. This way, when the player A quits, player B will immediately know that player A has quit.. Rather than waiting for gamecenter to notify you..

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. My game continues temporarily in the background using an iOS 4 background task, so I don't want the connection to be closed when the user hits the home button.

Comment: This is tricky.. haha.. since you want to application to run in BG when player A hits home button, how do you know if player A really wants to quit the game? Under what condition will the game disconnect??

Comment: The player has 20 seconds to do his turn.

Comment: means after 20seconds when the player A doesnt reply he get dc?
If player A press home button cause he wants to quit, player B has to wait 20 + 30 seconds??

Comment: Basically, yes. Because at that point it's not yet clear what the users intention was; quit or multitask to another app.

Comment: oh.. ok... in that case, put a timer for player B.. if he doesnt reply in 20seconds, dc then...